# How to test a stream in Dart

Tags: dart, reactive-programming

How to test a stream in dart? I have this code:

```dart
test('words are reading sequentially correct', () {
  WordTrackerInterface wordTracker = WordTracker.byContent('0 1 2');
  wordTracker.setWordsCountPerChunk(1);
  var stream = wordTracker.nextWordStringStream();

  expect(
      stream,
      emitsInOrder(List<Word>.generate(
          6, (i) => i > 2 ? Word('') : Word(i.toString()))));

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    wordTracker.nextWord();
  }
});
```

I need to test that the member data `Word::content` which is a `String` is equal to that provided in the `emitsInOrder`.

Something like the following for stream:

```dart
expect(
    stream,
    emitsInOrder(List<Word>.generate(
        6, (i) => i > 2 ? Word('') : Word(i.toString()))),
    expect((Word actual, Word expected) {
  return actual.content == expected.content;
}));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After reading the source code in dart files and reading on the internet, I found the solution: I needed to create a custom Matcher. I tested the following code on my laptop and by referencing other files from my application like 'WordTracker', the code ran as expected.

```
test('words are reading sequentially correct', () {
    WordTrackerInterface wordTracker = WordTracker.byContent('0 1 2');
    wordTracker.setWordsCountPerChunk(1);
    var stream = wordTracker.nextWordStringStream();

    expect(stream, 
      emitsInOrder(List<Word>.generate(6, (i) => i > 2 ? Word('') : Word(i.toString())).map<WordMatcher>(
        (Word value) => WordMatcher(value))));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      wordTracker.nextWord();
    }
  });


class WordMatcher extends Matcher {
  Word expected;
  Word actual;
  WordMatcher(this.expected);

  @override
  Description describe(Description description) {
    return description.add("has expected word content = '${expected.content}'");
  }

  @override
  Description describeMismatch(
    dynamic item,
    Description mismatchDescription,
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> matchState,
    bool verbose
  ) {
    return mismatchDescription.add("has actual emitted word content = '${matchState['actual'].content}'");
  }

  @override
  bool matches(actual, Map matchState) {
    this.actual = actual;
    matchState['actual'] = actual is Word ? actual : Word('unknown');
    return (actual as Word).content == expected.content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Try using `async`/`await` and `expectLater`

```
test('words are reading sequentially correct', () async {
  WordTrackerInterface wordTracker = WordTracker.byContent('0 1 2');
  wordTracker.setWordsCountPerChunk(1);
  var stream = wordTracker.nextWordStringStream();

  await expectLater(
      stream,
      emitsInOrder(List<Word>.generate(
          6, (i) => i > 2 ? Word('') : Word(i.toString()))));

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    wordTracker.nextWord();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin, thanks for your response, but what you've provided is not answering my question.  I want inside the emitsInOrder to check if what is emitted from Stream which is Word (object) and that the field 'content' which is of type 'String' is the same 'String' that is provided in the List<Word>.generate

Comment: Something like this (this code is hypothetical):
expect(stream, emitsInOrder(List<Word>.generate(
          6, (i) => i > 2 ? Word('') : Word(i.toString()))), 
(Word actual, Word expected) {
    return actual.content == expected.content;
});

Comment: How can I test stream created with broadcast stream controller?
```dart
final _eventsController = StreamController<DomainEvent>.broadcast();

Stream<DomainEvent> get events => _eventsController.stream;
```

Answer (score 9):

If your stream is emitting objects with properties you'd like to test, `expectAsync1` can help:

```
List<Record> expectedRecords = [record1, record2, record3];
int i = 0;
recordStream.listen(
    expectAsync1<void,Record>(
    (record) {
      expect(record.name, expectedRecords[i].name);
      i++;
    }, 
    max: -1)
);
```

In the above example, `expectAsync1` encloses an anonymous function:

```
    (record) {
      expect(record.name, expectedRecords[i].name);
      i++;
    }
```

This gets run each time a `Record` is emitted by the Stream `recordStream`

The `1` in `expectAsync1` is the number of arguments your enclosed function will take.  Most often, this would be 1. `(record)` is the one argument above.

For the above example, `expectAsync1` has (optional) type arguments: `<void,Record>` The 2nd type argument `Record` tells the enclosed function that the stream item emitted is of `Record` type, allowing me to use properties like `record.name` without casting.

The 1st type argument is the return type of your enclosed function.  I used `void` cause the enclosed function isn't returning anything, it's just running an `expect` Matcher and iterating a counter, which is used to iterate through the list of `Record` I'm expecting to see (i.e. `expectedRecords`) in that order.

#### Max argument

You'll notice the `max: -1` below the enclosed function.  That's an optional but important argument for `expectAsync1` specifying the number of stream items/events we're expecting.

**This defaults to `1` if `max` is not given** and your test ***will fail*** if more than 1 event is emitted.

The error will be `Callback called more times than expected (1).`

In the example above I used `-1` wich means unlimited events can be emitted/tested.  You can specify a non-zero number if you want to test you get exactly that many items/events from your stream, else the test will fail.  I could have used `max: 3` for my example above.

#### RxDart

If you're using RxDart `BehaviorSubject` remember the most recent stream event is emitted upon `listen`.  So in your test, when you start listening / using `expectAsync1` there will be an immediate call of the enclosed function with the most recent event.

`ReplaySubject` will emit all previous stream events upon `listen`.