# How to unit test Stream.listen() in Dart

Tags: unit-testing, dart, flutter-test

Consider the following test code ...

```dart
main() {
  StreamController controller;
  setUp(() {
    controller = StreamController.broadcast(sync: false);
  });

  tearDown(() {
    controller.close();
  });

  test('Stream listen test', () {
    var stream = controller.stream;

    stream.listen((event) {
      // >>>>> How can I test if this was called?? <<<<<<
    });

    controller.add('Here is an event!');
  });
}
```

... what is the correct way to test that the `stream.listen(...)` call-back was invoked?

`stream.listen(...)` doesn't return a `Future` so traditional `expectAsyncX` style matchers will not work here.

Perhaps there is some way to use the `StreamSubscription.asFuture()` that is returned by `stream.listen(...)`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [expectLater](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/expectLater.html) function to wait for `async` response from your `Stream` and compare your `Stream` to your emitted value using [emits](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-test_api_test_api/emits.html) , like this:

```
  test('Stream listen test', () {
    var stream = controller.stream;

    final String value = 'Here is an event!';

    stream.listen((event) {
      // >>>>> How can I test if this was called?? <<<<<<
    });

    expectLater(stream, emits(value));

    controller.add(value);
  });
```

**UPDATE**

You can try `expectAsync1` around your `listen` method. If no value is emitted, the timeout will be fired.

```
stream.listen(
      expectAsync1(
        (event) {
          expect(event, value);
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This will only confirm that the value was emitted ... not that the function inside `stream.listen()` was invoked.  I'm looking for a way to confirm that the listener was invoked.

Comment: It *will* confirm that the function was called. That is precisely what `expectAsync1` does: It wraps a function, and requires that the wrapper function is called, otherwise the test won't be successful. When the wrapper function is called, it will definitely call the function it wraps. So, if the test is successful, then you can be certain that the function argument to `expectAsync1` was also called (exactly once).

Comment: [Expanded example of `expectAsync1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63819777/2301224)

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks for the tip, not that easy to find in my opinion! Cheers!